# Access 2010 Parameter Query - AND OR

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a list of site details that I would like to query - returning only those where data is missing. I would like to give my users the ability to query the database returning information only for selected groups.

```
SELECT 
Lookup.Lookup_Name, 
Contacts.Address1, 
Contacts.Address2
FROM 
Contacts INNER JOIN Lookup ON Contacts.Group_1 = Lookup.Lookup_Code
WHERE (((Lookup.Lookup_Name)=[Site]) AND ((Contacts.Address1) Is Null)) OR (((Contacts.Address2) Is Null));
```

However this doesn't return the data from the selected site but from everything. I think it's the combination of the AND Or and associated parentheses. I have many more fields to add to the list so any advise is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MS-Access is very generous with their parentheses. Even if you don't place them, MS-Access will put them in - whether they are logically needed or not.

But there is also one logical fault in your query:
Your first lookup-condition was linked with `AND`only to the first address-empty-condition and the second address-empty-condition was simply linked by an `OR` which lead to the result that the empty address2 fields were shown from **all** rows (of all sites).

Try the following version:

```
SELECT 
Lookup.Lookup_Name, 
Contacts.Address1, 
Contacts.Address2,
Contacts.further1,
Contacts.further2,
Contacts.further3   -- and so on ...
FROM 
Contacts INNER JOIN Lookup ON Contacts.Group_1 = Lookup.Lookup_Code
WHERE ((Lookup.Lookup_Name)=[Site]) 
AND (  ((Contacts.Address1) Is Null) 
    OR ((Contacts.Address2) Is Null)
    OR ((Contacts.further1) Is Null)
    OR ((Contacts.further2) Is Null)
    OR ((Contacts.further3) Is Null)
    );
```

Currently I have no MS-Access installed on my computer so the above is not tested yet. I hope it works.